# retrieving specific value from a listview

Tags: c#, database, listview, code-behind

I have a select button in each row of my listview controler.  I am trying to create code behind in c# that will be able to get the ID of the specific column when a select button for that row is selected.  How can I get the value of ID for that specific row?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tag property to bind the id in each row and in your code for event handler access the tag. That would give you the id

```
Tag="{Binding id}"
```